Sublime Text's Terminus is not showing "Oh My Zsh icons"
Oh-my-Zsh icons are not showing in the terminus shell
When I open the powershell inside sublime text via "terminus" plugin, the Oh-my-zsh/oh-my-posh icons are not showing, instead i'm seeing "?" in place of style icons
Is there anything I can do to fix this?..like changing the terminus user-settings or something else
